# Whenever I try to enter a letter that in in the sentence it doesn't work?

Tags: python

```
sentence = ("ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO       FOR YOUR COUNTRY")


print (sentence)

keyword = input("Input a word from the sentence")

keyword_check = True

words = sentence.split(' ')

while keyword_check == True:
for w in range(len(keyword)):
    if keyword[w].isalpha():
        keyword = keyword.lower()

if keyword not in sentence:
    keyword = input("please enter a valid word")

else:

    for (i, subword) in enumerate(words):
        if (subword == keyword):
            print("your word is in position")
            print(i+1)
            keyword_check = False
```

as the title say when i try to enter just a letter that is in the sentence is stops the program and also if I don't enter anything it also stops the program help!

Comment: You say "just a letter" - are you entering a single letter, rather than an entire word? Once you split the sentence like that, it'll only find an exact match.

Comment: What do you mean by 'it stops the program'.

Comment: In your question it is unclear what the problem is. Post the exception your getting, so people can help you fast.

Comment: Also it's better to describe the goal you want to achieve ('How do I find the position of a given word in a given sentence") in the title instead to simple write what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

In Python2 `input` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))`, so your input will be evaluated. Not what you want for your example. Use `raw_input` to get user input as a string.

Just use `split()` to split your sentence. It uses white spaces as delimiter what will work better for multiple spaces in the sentence.

For comparisons it's always a good thing to know at which position to use `lower()` to ignore casing.

```
sentence = "ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO       FOR YOUR COUNTRY"
print(sentence)
words=sentence.lower().split()

while True:
  keyword = raw_input("Input a word from the sentence: ").lower()
  try:
    index=words.index(keyword)
  except ValueError: # is raised, when keyword is not found in words
    continue
  break

print("Found on index: %d"%words.index(keyword))
```

While answering your question a feeling arises in me that I've done your homework?